# Radio buttons not selecting in old program

Tags: c, windows, api, windows-xp

I wrote a large complex C program around 20(!) years go. As far as I can recall it worked fine at the time in all respects - it was probably running on windows 95.

Now I need to use it again. Unfortunately the radio buttons in it do not appear to work properly any more (the ordinary push buttons are all behaving correctly). As I click on the radio buttons, I get some feedback that windows is acknowledging my click in as much as I see a dotted line appear around the button's text and the circle of the button goes grey for as long as my finger is on the button, but when I take my finger off I see that the selected button has not changed.

My suspicion is that I was perhaps getting away with some bad practice at the time which worked with windows 95 but no longer works on newer versions of windows, but I'm struggling work out what I did wrong. Any ideas?

**EDIT:** Its difficult to extract the relevant code because the message handling in this program was a tangled nightmare. Many buttons were created programatically at runtime and there were different message loops working when the program was in different modes of operation. The program was a customisable environment for running certain types of experiment. It even had its own built-in interpreted language! So I'm not expecting an answer like "you should have a comma instead of a semicolon at line 47", but perhaps something more like "I observed similar symptoms once in my program and it turned out to be ..... " .. or perhaps "the fact that the dotted rectangle is appearing means that process AAA has happened, but maybe step BBB has gone wrong".

**EDIT:** I've managed to extract some key code which my contain an error...

```
char *process_messages_one_at_a_time()
{
    MSG msg;
    int temp;

    temp = PeekMessage(&msg,winh,0,0,PM_NOREMOVE);

    if (temp)
    {
        GetMessage (&msg, NULL, 0, 0);
        if (msg.message == WM_LBUTTONUP)
        {
            mouse_just_released_somewhere = TRUE;
        }

        TranslateMessage (&msg);
        DispatchMessage (&msg);
    }

    if (button_command_waiting)
    {
        button_command_waiting = FALSE;
        return (button_command_string);
    }
    else
    {
        return (NULL);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have any code we can look at?

Comment: This sounds like a case where you need to provide an SSCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct (Compilable) Example](http://sscce.org/)) so that people can see which APIs you're (mis)using.  You need to reduce the code to a single radio button and the minimum possible other code, though.  Have you looked on MSDN for information about the APIs you're trying to use?

Comment: I love SSCE's and have posted them many time before, but getting one together in this case it going to be mighty tricky... but I'll go back to my code and see what I can do.

Comment: You code looks strange indeed. Maybe you could try to replace the message loop by a standard one, and see if that fixes the RB issue (maybe if that breaks something else). At least you'll know if it comes from the message loop, which may not be the case.

Comment: Not sure it has something to do with your problem but, I see that you PeekMessage only for window winh, but you GetMessage right after on ALL window handles.

Answer (score 2):

There are two simple things to check when using radio buttons. First is to make sure that each has the BS_AUTORADIOBUTTON property set. The second is to make sure that the first button in the tab order and the next control after the set of buttons (typically a group box) have the WS_GROUP property set, while the other buttons have it clear.

Answer (score 1):

A few suggestions:

- I'd try to use spy++ to monitor the messages in that dialog box, particularly to and from the radiobutton controls. I wonder if you'll see a BM_SETCHECK that your program is sending (ie, somewhere you're unchecking the button programatically).
- Any chance your code ever checks the Windows version number? I've been burned a few times with  an == where I should have used a >= to ensure version checking compatibility.
- Do you sub-class any controls? I don't remember, but it seems to me there were a few ways sub-classing could go wrong (and the effects weren't immediately noticeable until newer versions of Windows rolled in).
- Owner-drawing the control? It's really easy to for the owner-draw to not work with newer Windows GUI styles.

Working with old code like that, the memories come back to me in bits and pieces, rather than a flood, so it usually takes some time before it dawns on me what I was doing back then.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to get the program running to use it, might I suggest "compatibility mode".

http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/using-windows-vista-compatibility-mode/

However, if you have a larger, expected useful life of the software, you might want to consider rewriting it. Rewriting it is not anywhere near the complexity or work of the initial write because of a few factors:

- Developing the requirements of a program is a substantial part of the required work in making a software package (the requirements are already done)
- A lot of the code is already written and only parts may need to be slightly refactored in order to be updated
- New library components may be more stable alternatives to parts of the existing codebase
- You'll learn how to write current applications with current library facilities
- You'll have an opportunity to comment or just generally refactor and cleanup the code (thus making it more maintainable for the anticipated, extended life)
- The codebase will be more maintainable/compatible going forward for additional changes in both requirements and operating systems (both because it's updated and because you've had the opportunity to re-understand the entire codebase)

Hope that helps...